# Error occured: System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#-2.0

I have a website that has been running for almost 6 months. There is a section on the site where the user uploads up to 5 property images. For every 10 users, I have one user who would run into a System.NotSupportedException issue. Since it doesn't happen to all the users and I can't seem to reproduce this error, I am not sure how to find a solution. Looking at the error message, i think it might have to do with their network configuration on their machine but I am not 100% sure. Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code where the uploading of the images takes place.

```
private void UploadPhotos()
{
    Stream objStream;
    HttpFileCollection uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    for (int i = 0; i < uploads.Count; i++)
    {
        if (uploads[i].ContentLength == 0)
            continue;
        try
        {
            string fileName = Path.Combine(image + "-" + i.ToString(), uploads[i].FileName);
            //uploads[i].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExtendedImages/") + fileName);
            using (new Impersonator("serverusername", @"serverlocation", "serverpassword!"))
            {
                try
                {
                    uploads[i].SaveAs(@"serverlocation" + fileName);
                }
                catch (NotSupportedException ex)
                {
                    uploads[i].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExtendedImages/") + fileName);
                }
            }
            //uploads[i].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExtendedImages/") + fileName);
            byte[] myimage = new byte[uploads[i].ContentLength];
            objStream = uploads[i].InputStream;
            objStream.Read(myimage, 0, uploads[i].ContentLength);

            System.Drawing.Image Image1;
            System.Drawing.Image Thumbnail;

            Image1 = new Bitmap(objStream);

            Image1.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);
            Image1.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipNone);

            int NewWidth = 380;
            int MaxHeight = 400;

            if (Image1.Width <= NewWidth)
            {
                NewWidth = Image1.Width;
            }

            int NewHeight = Image1.Height * NewWidth / Image1.Width;

            if (NewHeight > MaxHeight)
            {
                NewWidth = Image1.Width * MaxHeight / Image1.Height;
                NewHeight = MaxHeight;
            }
            System.Drawing.Image NewImage = Image1.GetThumbnailImage(NewWidth, NewHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            Thumbnail = Image1.GetThumbnailImage(100, 80, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            MemoryStream ms2 = new MemoryStream();
            Thumbnail.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            NewImage.Save(ms2, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Photos photos = new Photos();
            photos.ID = HomeTourSession.HometourName;
            photos.AdId = (int)Session["adid"];
            photos.FullPhoto = ms2.ToArray();
            photos.ThumbnailPhoto = ms.ToArray();
            photos.AlternateText = "";
            photos.Insert();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error occured: " + exp);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error some users are getting.

> Error occured: System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format
>   is not supported. at
>   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path,
>   Boolean needFullPath) at
>   System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[]
>   str, Boolean needFullPath) at
>   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess
>   access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean
>   checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList) at
>   System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess
>   access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathList, Boolean
>   checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath) at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) at
>   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) at

Comment: Log the path names passed to SaveAs() so you have some idea what is going wrong.  And **always** use Path.Combine() instead of `+`

Comment: Could i redirect them to an error page instead after catching the exception? This code might work, won't it?

Comment: Sorry, here is the code. catch (NotSupportedException ex)
                    {
                        uploads[i].SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/ExtendedImages/") + fileName);
                        Response.Redirect("~/Register/RegistrationErrorPage.aspx", false);
                    }